# problem with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've been using Visual Studio to code my C# project for a while, everything is seem to be okay until today, I modified code from [C# File Browser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx#Plug-ins) and use it in my project as component. After that I cannot change the Window Form icon (as same as I've done with others win form) when I browse the icon file Visual Studio become stop working. Moreover while I'm do the debugging with window form that have file browser, I try to test an function by browsing a file after I've browse a file VS also stop working. More and moreover sometime VS stop working by itself without any action by me. Anyone know where to seek for the cause or how to solve this.

I've solved the icon problem by using

```
this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico");
```

and set the properties of image:

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to output Directory: Always
```

after I've installed VS 2010 service pack 1 the icon problem can be solve, I can browse the icon file in properties but another fail on debugging still the same and I've got

```
exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).
```

which seem to be cause by the file browser library

Comment: Are you having issues with any other apps? Have you installed the VS2010 service pack?

Comment: It's work well with other apps and nope I haven't

Comment: If you don't have the service packs installed, you might want to start there.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: thx for all of your answer now i'm installing service packs ,it's so slow

Comment: I had issues with VS2010 crashing/freezing on me. Make sure you have the newest video drivers for your PC. That helped me with the freezing issues a TON.

Comment: On this subject, you could also turn off hardware acceleration and rich client (Under Tools -> Options -> Environment - General)

Comment: Did the SP resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does, but there's also another problem from the library I use

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had a lot of crashing going on also.

I was able to get my website solution functional again by deleting the Solution User Options files.

.suo files, under your profile ( OS dependent )
(My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\solutionName for xp, unless you have your .sln someplace else.)
(NOTE: You right click a solution on the start page, and open Containing Folder.)

solutionName.sln.docstates.suo
is one of them.  This cleared up the problem i was experiencing, but then caused other issues.
and
solutionName.suo

Do realize, this will lose ALL settings you have made for this solution.

However, it can clear things up.

I believe that once you get a crash, you can get garbage in these files.
In some cases, it may also be necessary to delete the .sln file itself.

As always, keep a copy of these files just in case...